# Confusion regarding calculation of fundamental period?

Tags: signal-analysis, periodic, fundamental-frequency

I am reading signal processing first and in chapter 3 ex3.8 i came across an example of fundamental period as shown  in attached photo

It apparently shows that signal $$x(t)=\cos^2(4\pi t)$$ has period 0.5 but then it also writes that fundamental period is 0.25

How is he doing that?

Also will be fundamental period if $$x(t)=\cos^n(4\pi t)$$ where n can be 3 or 4 or 5
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trigonometric functions are essentially exponential.  Thus, a doubling of the argument corresponds to a squaring of the function (in a sense).  In this case, it can be seen by applying the angle addition formula:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\cos( 2\theta ) &= \cos( \theta + \theta ) \\
&= \cos(\theta)\cos(\theta) - \sin(\theta)\sin(\theta) \\
&= \cos^2(\theta) - ( 1- \cos^2(\theta) ) \\
&= 2 \cos^2(\theta) -  1
\end{aligned}
$$

Making

$$ \cos^2(\theta) = \frac{\cos( 2\theta ) + 1}{2} $$

Applying it to your equation:

$$ x(t)=\cos^2(4\pi t) = \frac{\cos( 8 \pi t ) + 1}{2} $$

From this it is pretty clear the fundamental period is 0.25 as that makes $8 \pi t = 2\pi$.

---

Upon request:

$$
\begin{aligned}
x(t) &= \cos^3(4\pi t) \\
&= \left( \frac{ e^{i 4\pi t} + e^{-i 4\pi t} }{2} \right)^3 \\
&= \frac{1}{8}\left( e^{i 12\pi t} + 3 e^{i 4\pi t} + 3 e^{-i 4\pi t} + e^{-i 12\pi t}  \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{4}\left[ \cos(12\pi t)  + 3 \cos( 4\pi t) \right] \\
\end{aligned}
$$

You should be able to figure from there.  Note, the squared case could have been handled the same way.

I use this technique extensively for these formulas:

- [Exact Near Instantaneous Frequency Formulas Best at Peaks (Part 1)](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1051.php)
- [Exact Near Instantaneous Frequency Formulas Best at Peaks (Part 2)](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1056.php)
- [Exact Near Instantaneous Frequency Formulas Best at Zero Crossings](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1074.php)

Comment: Please kindly update 2nd last line of your answer. It is fundamental period that is 0.25 not fundamental frequency

Comment: @Man Done, good catch.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Please kindly make a bit update to your answer to meet the need of updated question

Comment: @Man Quit shifting the goal posts.  n=3,4,5... can be calculated according to the pattern.  the end result is $n4 \pi T=2 \pi $ which is the same as $T=1/(2n)$

Answer (score 3):

This seems like more of a semantics problem.

A signal is periodic with time $T$ if

$$x(t+n\cdot T) = x(t), n \in \mathbb{Z}$$

So the signal is periodic in $0.5$ since the for $T = 0.5 \cdot n$ the argument of the cosine is an integer multiple of $2 \pi$. Since it's periodic in $0.5$ it's also periodic in all integer multiples of $0.5$, i.e $1$, $1.5$, $2$ etc.

In this case it's also periodic in $0.25$ since 
$$ \cos^2(4 \cdot \pi \cdot t ) = 0.5 \cdot (1+\cos(8 \cdot \pi \cdot t))$$

So any periodic signal has an infinite number of periods, the fundamental one is the smallest one and all the others are integer multiples of the fundamental.

Answer (score 2):

If it helps any, generate a unit amplitude sinewave at 1 Hz and its square:

[image: Sine and square generation]

Then the sinewave and its square look like this:

[image: Sinewave and its square]

You can see the DC component: the averaged value of the squared sinewave (averaged over an integer number of periods) is 1/2. And the red sinewave frequency is exactly doubled, so the period is halved. The DC and doubled frequency are the 'beat frequencies' obtained by multiplying the sinewave by itself.

Comment: what software are you using?

Comment: I am using a commercial simulation program named Extend (older version) and ExtendSim (newer versions), from Imagine That, Inc. These are augmented with four libraries of blocks I started developing back in 1990. My libraries, named LightStone, are available for free, with full commented source code. The URL for my libraries is https://umass.box.com/v/LightStone. I will be updating the libraries by the end of the week so that they work with the latest ExtendSim 10.0.6 version (should be just a recompile). The model above was done with Extend 6.0.8 on an old Mac (I like the way it looks).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out :)

Comment: My LightStone libraries are finally, after 1.5 years stuck at what appeared to be an unfixable bug, fully functioning with the latest ExtendSim CP version: v. 10.0.8. A very welcome development and weight off my chest. But the URL above is now dead: the host went away. One thing after another.